# Problem importing a module in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, windows-10, ide

Hi I'm having problems trying to import a matplotlib module in PyCharm. It works when I do "import matplotlib", and "import matpolotlib.pyplot as plt" , but not when I try to "from matplotlib import style"

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

[image: Screenshot of project interpreter if that helps.]

Comment: You have a typo `matplolib` -> `matplotlib`

Comment: I facepalmed at that lmao thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do NOT import `matplolib` import `matplotlib`

if not working try `pip install matplotlib`